# Confusion with the order of execution when `next` with `unless` in ruby

Tags: ruby

The `next` statement is used to skip a part of the loop and continue with the next iteration of the loop. It can be used in combination with `for` and `while` statements.

I have seen people using next if there is complicated piece of code after some condition is being evaluated i.e

```
next if @state!=:some_state
# some long complicated code
```

Now here I have played with the `next` in my `IRB` as below :

```
n = 1
loop do
  n = n + 1
  next unless n == 10
  print "Good"
  break
end
# Good=> nil
```

The above one understood. Nicely clear.

```
n = 1
#=> 1
loop do
  print "#{n}"
  n = n + 1
  next puts "hi" unless n == 5
  p "good"
  break
end
#1hi
#2hi
#3hi
#4"good"
#=> nil
```

In the above code, couldn't understand about which order the lines `puts "hi"` and `unless n == 5` executed. Which executed first?

The below one leads to the `infinite Loop`.

```
n = 1
#=> 1
loop do
  print "#{n}"
  n = n + 1
  next puts "hi"; 2 + 3 unless n == 5
  p "good"
  break
end
```

whereas this one is good:

```
n = 1
#=> 1
loop do
  print "#{n}"
  n = n + 1
  next puts "hi", 2 + 3 unless n == 5
  p "good"
  break
end

#1hi
#5
#2hi
#5
#3hi
#5
#4"good"
#=> nil
```

Please help me here to understand - how does this one resolve that `forever` loop ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [is returning a value from 'next' a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561187/is-returning-a-value-from-next-a-bad-idea)

Comment: @sawa: this isn't really related, as the OP wants to understand when `next` will be executed based on an attempted conditional modifier

Comment: @sawa Could you please remove that link,as no way it is connected with my question?

Comment: Your question involves execution of the return value of `next`, which is what that linked question is about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A semicolon is evaled as a line break so:

```
next puts "hi"; 2 + 3 unless n == 5
```

would be equivalent to:

```
next puts "hi"
2 + 3 unless n == 5
```

Therefore, `next` will always be called and you'll have an infinite loop.

The comma is evaled as passing a set of arguments (which is interpreted as an array by `puts` method signature), so:

```
next puts "hi", 2 + 3 unless n == 5
```

is equivalent to:

```
next puts("hi", 2 + 3) unless n == 5
```

Regarding the execution order of `puts` and `unless` - consider the following:

```
unless n == 5
  next puts "hi"
end
```

In this example, it is obvious that `unless` is evaluated first, then if the condition passed is evaluated to false the `next puts "hi"` statement is executed.  Well:

```
next puts "hi" unless n == 5
```

is shorthand for exactly the same thing.  So the `unless` modifier will always be evaluated first.  Naturally, if you insert a semicolon in the middle, it would cause this to be evaluated differently, since the semicolon is evaluated as a line break.

Comment: Could you help me with my first question?

Comment: thanks for taking care my pain. I was keep waiting from you to hear the rest.At last you heard my ones. :) I am happy

Comment: `next` generally used to skip the part of execution and send the control to the beginning. But how the in between part `puts "hi"` has been executed. Why does `next` not skip this statement ?

Comment: Then `next` method accepts an argument, so it is the same as writing `next(puts "hi")`

Answer (score 0):

The conditional has to execute first, otherwise, how would it even know whether to evaluate any expressions involving the statement?

As to your second question, the value of the **next** expression is ignored for loops, the value in the expression is only useful to return a value from a block. So, the only thing that makes your loop end is the **break**.

Comment: Could you bit explain your answer just for clear understanding? in the line `next puts "hi" unless n == 5` when condition evaluated to `false`, `next` is executed but then control should go to the beginning of the block. But if so then how `puts "hi"` has been executed. Here I am too much confused. How this kind of statement worked in reality?

Comment: Although it is true that the expression passed to `next` inside a loop will not be returned, it will still be evaluated.  Which is why `next puts "hi"` will generate output.